# How To Add Dummy Data In JSON Array to a CardView in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm working on android parsing JSON data and display it to a CardView using RecyclerView. And i ask how to populate the CardView with JSON dummy data from string declared not from the internet API.

Can i use adapter?

Anyone with an idea on how to do that can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Populate the CardView with JSON dummy data from string declared not from the internet API. Can i use adapter?

Yes you can. The steps are simple enough :

---

1. Add the `json` files to `assets` folder (path : `src/main/assets/`)

---

In your `Activity` :

2. Read the data from these JSON files and store it in a string.

   ```
   /**
    * Get JSON data from file (dummyData)
    * @return String
    */
   public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
       String json = null;
       try {

           //JSON file is in src/main/assets/dummData.json
           InputStream is = getAssets().open("dummyData.json");
           int size = is.available();
           byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
           is.read(buffer);
           is.close();
           json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           return null;
       }
       return json;
   }
   ```

---

3. Now pass the data string to your JSON object.

   ```
   /**
    * Get the JSON data from Response
    */
   public void getJSONobj()
   {
         try {
               mJSONarray = new JSONArray(loadJSONFromAsset());
         } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
         }
   }
   ```

---

4. So now you have got the JSON data (just like how you would if you were getting `Response` after HTTP Request). Just use the `mJSONarray` data to populate the `RecyclerView` as you normally would.

**Note** : Storing the `JSON` data in file for easier manageability and modularity.

Comment: Thank you! is there a way you can declare a string with json data instead of retrieving from the asset file?

Comment: Yes, just declare a String with the JSON data in it, and use that in Step `3.`

Comment: Though for manageability its better to use files. Makes your life easier and debugging process becomes smaller.

Comment: Sure. Glad to help.